# Google Analytics: Is it possible to filter the raw data to create more valuable indicators?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, threshold

We would like to build indicators that provide more useful information than "averages", e.g. instead of having to rely on "average time on page", we would like to create an indicator like "unique users that spent more than [threshold] time on page".

In order to do this, we need to know, whether Google Analytics is storing information on "user session" in connection with "time on page" in its raw data? And if it does, whether this raw data is accessible and can be filtered?

Another situation where the mentioned storing and filtering might come in handy, is the following: if different activities (e.g. post comment, click like, ...) are all tracked with regard to user session, we could build an indicator like: "unique users that performed any of the following: comment, like, ...".

Any reply, remark or comment is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw data is not accessible in Google Analytics.

The closest you will get, if you have a GA360 account, is the [BigQuery export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en), but even that is not "raw" in any meaningful sense (although it is more detailed). You could create a custom [sendHitTask](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#overriding_a_task) to send raw data to your own database.

But raw data would be not useful to you, since GA does not send session data with the raw data. Since 2012/the introduction of Universal Analytics, sessions are entirely calculated on the Google servers - the aforementioned BigQuery export would actually be more useful, since data there is already sessionized, but this requires the paid-for version of GA.

Usually there are workaround for most use cases - i.e. "more than time x" can be viewed as categorical data instead of as metric, so if you send a timestamp in seconds (starting with 0 for the first page view) with each hit to a session scoped custom dimension GA will only retain the last value per session. Then you can filter by all users where that dimension is bigger a given value (you need to use a regex, since you cannot compare dimensions as numbers, and I recommend to create "buckets" instead of having too many discrete values).

But to answer the explicit question, there is no access to raw data (unless you store it yourself) and it would not contain session data in any case.